# In which condition the buffer get full

Tags: c, stream, buffer

I am reading about stream and buffer.
I got that if stream is **line buffered** then the accumulated characters of buffer get transfered in the from of block whenever the newline character encounter.
and if stream is **unbuffered** then character are intended to appear from the source or appear at the destination as soon as possible without getting store in buffer.

but if stream is **fully buffered** then the accumulated characters of buffer get transfered in the form of block *whenever the buffer get totally filled*.
**Now I am unable to understand that in which condition the buffer get totally filled**.

Comment: The "buffer" have a max-size. This max-size is stored in a variable. Checking if a buffer is full is simply something like `current_size == max_size` or similar.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude means the the stream will check the maximum size of variable in which data will get store from the buffer, and in this way It's decide the maximum size of the buffer..

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude If it is so, then there will be no chance of buffer overflow in any condition.

Comment: The implementation keeps track of the size. There's no chance of an overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C standard does not explicitly specify the details of stream buffering, but generally a stream has a buffer of fixed size. This is simply an array of bytes that is used for holding data for the stream.

Quite simply, the buffer is totally filled when the number of bytes that have been written to the stream since the last time the buffer was flushed equals the number of bytes in the buffer.

When `<stdio.h>` is included, it defines a macro `BUFSIZ` that provides the size of the buffer used by `setbuf`. You can print it with `printf("%d\n", BUFSIZ);`. Presumably that is the default size of a buffer for a stream, although the C standard does not explicitly say this. (It says that is the size of the buffer used by the `setbuf` function, which allows you to provide your own memory for the buffer.)

You can also use the newer `setvbuf` to request a different size for the buffer. Both `setbuf` and `setvbuf` must be used only just after a stream has been opened and before any other operation.

Comment: Thanks for satisfactory fast response. Is it correct that "Maximum size of buffer is equal to the maximum size of array or variable in which data is transmit from the buffer"

Comment: But I have a doubt if it is so as above then what is the cause of buffer overflow ? Because every I/O done using streams which are standard I/O then it check the size of buffer every time and then there will no chance of buffer Overflow. But we know that in some functions like gets(), buffer Overflow happens.

Comment: @Suraj: Buffer overflow typically refers to a case in which some buffer is managed by a program directly. For example, given `char a[100]; scanf("%s", a);`, the array `a` can overflow because no limit is given to tell `scanf` when to stop. This is an error by the programmer. In contrast, the I/O routines declared in `<stdio.h>` are generally well written and manage their buffers correctly.

Comment: In 2nd paragraph, you have written that the **size of buffer become equal to the previous size of buffer that has been already flushed**, but how can the size of buffer reamain same after every flushing because *the size of buffer depend on the variable or array  to or from which the transmission of data takes place*.